# MySql: How to Delete rows from a table EXCEPT a row with specific ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have an html table with checkboxes. Users are permitted to delete rows from that html table except one specific one, whose value is hard coded in the DB.

If a user accidently checks it regardless, I want my server code (php) or even better the MySqL to run a delete query for all the rows they checked EXCEPT for that 1 specific row. So,something like this( which is wrong):

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE row_id = some_value
EXCEPT row_id = some_value;
```

Many thanks !

Comment: there's no `except`. use inequality: `where row_id != do_not_delete_this_value`

Comment: Better put an if statement, validating the input, and print an error to the user, if he checks the wrong row, instead of adding logics into SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DELETE FROM table_name WHERE row_id NOT IN (do_not_delete_this_value );

do_not_delete_this_value  will be the id of the row you don't want to delete, rest all records will get deleted.

Answer (score 3):

I think the logic you want is `AND`:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE row_id = some_value AND row_id <> some_value;
```

Of course, `some_value` should be different most of the time.

Comment: It's redundant anyways, `delete ... where row_id=42` would never delete any other row_id to begin with. `where row_id=42 and row_id<>69`?

Comment: @MarcB . . . The OP is trying to prevent `where row_id = 69`.  Admittedly, this could be done at the application level, but as a query:`where row_id = 69 and row_id <> 69` also does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there are a couple of ways to do it, for deleting all row's except one specific ID, type the following command in SQL query:

> In between parentheses, type the ID number that you want to keep.

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `ID` NOT IN (1)
```

Also, to delete all records except some id's, use this command:

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `ID` NOT IN (1,2,6,10)
```